# SessionId changes when logging in with IDP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, saml

I am working with some legacy code on a bug fix regarding a login redirect. In short, when a user loads  a page which has a link to the login page, clicks on the login link which goes to our SSO login page, and then logs in on that SSO page, they are not redirected to the home page instead of the page they were at last. Investigating this, the way the previous developers solved this was to save the "deep link" as a variable in the session data (which has its session id saved in a cookie on the client and in memory on the server). The user, in theory, when they log in should then have that deep link retrieved from the session data and then they should be redirected. However, this is where the issue is found: the session id in this second call (when the user logs in) has a different session id and thus the matching deep link is not found among this session id's session data.

I can prove the session id is properly stored in the cookie in Chrome and SAML Tracer, and the SAML calls happen in succession with no other calls happening in between. I don't see the session id being passed in parameters or http headers (although the correct link the user should go to once logged in is passed as the referer in the first SSO request).

I should also note, we are using ComponentSpace's SAML library. Also, when the initial call to go to the SSO page, a 302 Found error appears when this is redirected. I think this is intentional, but I am not 100% sure. The SSO is ADFS.

Nobody who worked on this code is in the company anymore, and both this code base and these libraries are new to me. I am also unsure if this is an issue with this application or the custom SSO website we connect to, and I need to prove it one way or the other. None of our code relating this issue has been changed in 2 or more years according to TFS.

My questions:

1. Why does the session id change from the first call to the second?
2. Is there additional setup required for keeping the session data from call to call? Don't I want different session ids for different calls in general?
3. How does the session persist for a single user?
4. How do I prove if the issue is a change with our application or the one we connect to?

Here is the code of the first SSO call when the user clicks on the link to the sign in page:

```
public ActionResult SingleSignOn()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ssoUrl))
            {
                _accountRespository.SetDeepLink();
                var sessionId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
                // Redirect to SSO Site. Reentry point is Controllers/SAMLController.cs::AssertionConsumerService() .
                return Redirect(ssoUrl);
```

Here is the code for the second call after clicks the login button with their credentials:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssertionConsumerService()
    {
        try
        {
            bool isInResponseTo = false;
            string partnerIdP = null;
            string userName = null;
            IDictionary<string, string> claims = null;
            string relayState = null;
            var sessionId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
            SAMLServiceProvider.ReceiveSSO(Request, out isInResponseTo, out partnerIdP, out userName, out claims, out relayState);

            // Resolve the page redirect.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relayState))
            {
                // If relayState is not provided by ADFS, get it from the session variable.
                relayState = _accountRepository.GetDeepLink();
                _accountRepository.ClearDeepLink();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relayState))
                {
                    // If no target URL is provided, default back to the home page.
                    relayState = "~/";
                }
            }
```

Here is the code for the SetDeepLink and GetDeepLink calls:

```
public string GetDeepLink()
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Can't access deep link session variable. HttpContext.Current is null.");
        }
        return (string)httpContext.Session[Constants.SessionDeepLinkUrl];
    }

public void SetDeepLink()
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Can't access deep link session variable. HttpContext.Current is null.");
        }
        var queryString = httpContext.Request.Url.Query;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
        {
            var deepLink = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)?.Get(Constants.DeepLinkQueryString);
            httpContext.Session[Constants.SessionDeepLinkUrl] = deepLink;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome and other browsers recently introduced changes to how the SameSite attribute of cookies is handled. This potentially impacts all cookies, including the ASP.NET session cookie, when participating in SAML SSO. I suspect this is the issue you're seeing.

You need to specify SameSite=None and Secure for the ASP.NET session cookie. This can be done by updating you application web.config with:

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
```

For more detailed information, please refer to:

https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/10816/Application-Cookie-SameSite-None

Comment: Yep. Tested it locally and that is exactly what it was. Adding in the sessionState attribute and the httpCookies were all I needed. Thank you.